# Get Handle of Metro mode Google Chrome

Tags: c#, google-chrome, url, ui-automation

I am trying to get access to UI controls of Google Chrome in Metro mode to get the current URL.

I have used the "Inspector" tool (C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86\inspect.exe) to get HWND of Chrome in Desktop mode. It works fine, but when I tried to get access for Chrome in Metro mode it just display one global HWND without child windows.

For Google Chrome in Desktop mode I use the UI automation framework to get the URL:

Could you please help with getting the access of UI controls in Metro mode of Chrome?

```
var element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hWnd);

    if (element == null)
        return PageInfo.Empty;

    var addressBar = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants,
        new AndCondition(new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.NameProperty, "Address and search bar"),
            new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit)));

    if (addressBar == null)
        return PageInfo.Empty;

    var url = ((ValuePattern)addressBar.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).Current.Value;
```

Comment: Did you try running "chrome.exe --force-render-accessibility"?

Comment: Yes, i tried by running chrome with "--force-render-accessibility" parameter but not succeed. chrome://accessibility/ shows URL in its tree but when I am trying from program, it doesn't have any child. It always returns child count 0. Is there is any way to get chrome - metro mode window handle with all children.

Comment: Probably you also need to set `UIAccess="true"` in the Application Manifest File as it mentioned in [the MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/desktop/ee671610(v=vs.85).aspx#ManifestFiles).